# SoundCloud API Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, soundcloud

I'm having trouble with the authentication part of the SoundCloud API. I am following the tutorial located here: http://developer.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#authentication

I follow their code as written and it runs/compiles, but doesn't authenticate. When requesting a login from the following bit of code:

```
(IBAction) login:(id) sender
{
    SCLoginViewControllerCompletionHandler handler = ^(NSError *error) {
        if (SC_CANCELED(error)) {
            NSLog(@"Canceled!");
        } else if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Done!");
        }
    };

    [SCSoundCloud requestAccessWithPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler:^(NSURL *preparedURL) {
        SCLoginViewController *loginViewController;

        loginViewController = [SCLoginViewController
                               loginViewControllerWithPreparedURL:preparedURL
                                            completionHandler:handler];
        [self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
    }];
```

It returns with a console error of:

```
2013-12-26 16:11:23.902 SampleProject[14748:4717] -[NXOAuth2PostBodyStream open] 
Stream has been reopened after close
2013-12-26 16:11:24.198 SampleProject[14748:70b] Done!
```

And then subsequent calls to [SCSoundCloud account] return nil.

During use of the app, the login views appear and I appear to have logged in successfully, but no account appears to have been saved / registered. Any advice?

Also, my initialization function with clientID / section / redirectURL are as directed in the tutorial and the app is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NXOAuth2Account.m where the user's client ID, client secret etc. are used to create the oauthClient.

You can also find in this file a method called description that should return everything you need to re-authenticate the user should you want to do so:

```
- (NSString *)description;
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<NXOAuth2Account identifier:'%@' accountType:'%@' accessToken:%@ userData:%@>", self.identifier, self.accountType, self.accessToken, self.userData];
}
```